# How to skip first three posts from blog list?

Tags: php, mysql, post

Hi anone who know how to skip first three posts from blog list,becouse i want first three to be featured on the  top...?

```
<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ";
$select_all_posts_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts_query)){
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,255);
    $post_status = $row['post_status'];

    if($post_status !== 'published') {

        echo "<h1 class='text-center'> NO POST SORRY</h1>";

    } else {

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing the last `}`. Is that just a copy/paste miss?

Comment: copy paste miss
 <?php  } } ?>

Answer (score 2):

use

```
LIMIT 3, X
```

which X is your limit

So the query must be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 3, X";
```

If you want get all from 3, then is should be 18446744073709551615 (Maximum row of MYISAM - from stackoverflow... lol)

Comment: Maybe you should mention that it is in the SQL query this goes?

Comment: that is so basic to say where to put LIMIT in query but thank you btw @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Never assume that other people understand what you mean. It's always best to be explicit. There are a lot of beginners here that have never used, or even heard about LIMIT.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT 3, X"; working tnx

Comment: @Electrobox You need to change `X` to the number of posts you want to retrieve.